# Lipschitz continuity and integration.

Tags: definite-integrals, continuity

I'm re-reading some material from Apostol's Calculus. He asks to prove that, if $f$ is such that, for any $x,y\in[a,b]$ we have

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq|x-y|$$

then:

$(i)$ $f$ is continuous in $[a,b]$

$(ii)$ For any $c$ in the interval,

$$\left|\int_a^b f(x)dx-(b-a)f(c)\right|\leq\frac{(b-a)^2}{2}$$

The proof for the first part is easy, and I ommit it. I'm interested in the second one.

We can write that as

$$\left| {\int_a^b f (x)dx - \int_a^b f (c)dx} \right| \leqslant \frac{{{{(b - a)}^2}}}{2}$$

Or $$\left| {\int_a^b {\left( {f(x) - f(c)} \right)dx} } \right| \leqslant \frac{{{{(b - a)}^2}}}{2}$$

Now, it is not hard to show that

$$\left| {\int_a^b {\left( {f(x) - f(c)} \right)dx} } \right| \leqslant \int_a^b {\left| {f(x) - f(c)} \right|dx} $$

By hypothesis, we have

$$\left| {f(x) - f(c)} \right| \leqslant \left| {x - c} \right|$$

so that

$$\left| {\int_a^b {\left( {f(x) - f(c)} \right)dx} } \right| \leqslant \int_a^b {\left| {f(x) - f(c)} \right|dx}  \leqslant \int\limits_a^b {\left| {x - c} \right|dx} $$

The last term, integrates as follows:

$$\int\limits_a^b {\left| {x - c} \right|dx}  =  - \int\limits_a^c {\left( {x - c} \right)dx}  + \int\limits_c^b {\left( {x - c} \right)dx}  = \frac{{{{\left( {b - c} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {a - c} \right)}^2}}}{2}$$

How can I conciliate that with $$\frac{{{{\left( {b - a} \right)}^2}}}{2}?$$

I'd like to know what happens in the general case

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq \lambda |x-y|$$
too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to write $$(b-a)^2= ((b-c)-(a-c))^2= (b-c)^2+ (a-c)^2-2(b-c)(a-c) \geq (b-c)^2+(a-c)^2$$ because $(b-c)(a-c) \leq 0$.

For your second question, consider $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\lambda} f$ and apply your first result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to prove
$$
(b-c)^2 + (a-c)^2 \le (b-a)^2.
$$
A bit of algebra reduces this to
$$
c^2-bc-ac+ab \le 0.
$$
Factor by grouping:
$$
(c-a)(c-b)\le 0.
$$
This just says $c$ is between $a$ and $b$.  It says that regardless of whether $a\le b$ or $b\le a$.

Comment: Hm, lazy, lazy me.

Comment: Why do we chose to consider the less tight bound?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean here.  If you mean $(a-b)^2/2$ rather than $(b-c)^2/2+(a-c)^2/2$, it could be that that is considered because it doesn't depend on $c$.

Answer (score 1):

I like pictures...

[image]

$\frac{(c-a)^2}{2} + \frac{(b-c)^2}{2} = m(T_1)+m(T_2)  \leq \frac{m(R_1)+m(R_2)}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2} (b-a) \max(c-a,b-c) \leq \frac{1}{2} (b-a)^2$.

Comment: Why do we chose to consider the less tight bound?

Comment: It is tight in the sense that $\sup_c lhs = rhs$, and the rhs is a formula without $c$.

Comment: Yes, I know, my question is why do you prefer a less tight bound in this case.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you mean why not use the formula with $c$? No reason, other than the homework...

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(c) = \dfrac{(b-c)^2+ (a-c)^2}{2}$. Then $f´(c) = (a-c)+(b-c)$. Hence, $f$ decreases of $a$ to $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and increases of $\dfrac{a+b}{2}$ to $b$. Hence $\dfrac{(a+b)^2}{2}=f(a)\ge f(c)$ to $a\le c\le \dfrac{a+b}{2}$ and $f(c) \le \dfrac{(a+b)^2}{2}=f(b)$ to $\dfrac{a+b}{2}\le c \le b$. Namely,
$f(c) \le \dfrac{(a+b)^2}{2}$ to $c\in[a,b]$.